# report portal status interrupted after long wait in tests

Tags: reportportal, wdio-v5

We use report portal to report automatic tests from WDIO.
I have noticed, that after long waits in the tests (waiting for a field to be updated in the database, before continuing with the test for example) report portal stops reporting and the test get the status of interrupted.

could found anything about this on internet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some Wdio call (like $(element).isExist(), may throw an error, and NodeJS will throw an exception that if its unhandled, then test status in Report Portal will be interrupted